# How can I write list of map as a value for individual key in yaml file from properties file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, arraylist, yaml, application.properties

I have a .properties file which has URL in this format

```
Url={activeUrl=100.31.142.16:8992, standByUrl=100.31.142.16:8992}, {activeUrl=100.32.142.16:8993, standByUrl=100.31.142.16:8993}
```

I want to get this Url value from properties file and write into yaml file using shell script. But I can't find any way of doing this.

.properties example file input:

```
vip="[xxxx:200:1413:100::z:xxxx]"               
InterfaceName="bond0.16,bond0.15"
smIp="0.0.0.0"
nCluster="002,003"
nIpVersion="ipv6,ipv6"
probeHost="xx.32.142.xxx:8992"
simulatorUrl="xx.32.136.xxx:9336"
bsfUrl={activeUrl=10.32.142.164:8992, standByUrl=10.32.142.164:8992}, 
{activeUrl=10.32.142.164:8993, standByUrl=10.32.142.164:8993}
```

Example yaml output:

```
vip: "[xxxx:200:1413:100::z:xxxx]"
InterfaceName: "bond0.16,bond0.15"
smIp: "0.0.0.0"
nCluster: "002,003"
nIpVersion: "ipv6,ipv6"
probeHost: "xx.32.142.xxx:8992"
simulatorUrl: "xx.32.136.xxx:9336"
bsfUrl: 
  - 
    activeUrl: "10.32.142.164:8992"
    standByUrl: "10.32.142.164:8992"
  - 
    activeUrl: "10.32.142.164:8993"
    standByUrl: "10.32.142.164:8993"
```

Comment: You should add the wanted YAML output corresponding to your entry. Also, does the `.properties` file have only one line ?

Comment: I have edited the question please check.

Comment: Last questions, about the `.properties` file format. Is there any possibility for the value of a property to spread across multiple lines? Can there be any spaces surrounding the `=`? Can there be any nested `{}`? - I hope the response is no to all the three questions. Also, sometimes the values are double-quoted and other times not, why is that?

Comment: Yes the response of all three question is     no.   In bsfUrl I forgot to double quote it. All key value pair is double quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r property
do
    IFS='=' read -r name value <<< "$property"
    case $value in
    \"*)
        printf '%s: %s\n' "$name" "$value"
        ;;
    \{*)
        printf '%s:\n' "$name"
        value="${value//\}, {/$'\n'}"; value="${value//[,{\}]/ }"
        while read -r -a subproperties
        do
            printf '  -\n'
            for subproperty in "${subproperties[@]}"
            do
                IFS='=' read -r subname subvalue <<< "$subproperty"
                printf '    %s: %s\n' "$subname" "$subvalue"
            done
        done <<< "$value"
        ;;
      *)
        echo "error: invalid line format \`$property'" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done < <(cat -- "${@:--}")
```

***note:** using `cat` for convenience (allows input from stdin, files, or both at the same time)*

input:

```
vip="[xxxx:200:1413:100::z:xxxx]"
InterfaceName="bond0.16,bond0.15"
smIp="0.0.0.0"
nCluster="002,003"
nIpVersion="ipv6,ipv6"
probeHost="xx.32.142.xxx:8992"
simulatorUrl="xx.32.136.xxx:9336"
bsfUrl={activeUrl="10.32.142.164:8992", standByUrl="10.32.142.164:8992"}, {activeUrl="10.32.142.164:8993", standByUrl="10.32.142.164:8993"}
```

output:

```
vip: "[xxxx:200:1413:100::z:xxxx]"
InterfaceName: "bond0.16,bond0.15"
smIp: "0.0.0.0"
nCluster: "002,003"
nIpVersion: "ipv6,ipv6"
probeHost: "xx.32.142.xxx:8992"
simulatorUrl: "xx.32.136.xxx:9336"
bsfUrl:
  -
    activeUrl: "10.32.142.164:8992"
    standByUrl: "10.32.142.164:8992"
  - 
    activeUrl: "10.32.142.164:8993"
    standByUrl: "10.32.142.164:8993"
```

---

###### Limitations

Doesn't work as expected in the following cases:

- newlines in values

```sh
vip="I'm
 God"
bsfUrl={
  activeUrl="10.32.142.164:8992"
}
```

- spaces around `=`

```
vip = "[xxxx:200:1413:100::z:xxxx]"
```

- commas, braces or spaces in string literals when they appear in a *braced* property (you would need a real parser to handle that)

```
bsfUrl={comma=","}, {closingBrace="}", space=" "}
```

- unquoted values (the code will explicitly fail)

```
vip=I'm God
```